# string.equals(string2) returns false though both strings are exactly same, even in length

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do an operation when two strings are different. The strings are actually time and am checking to see if the new time i obtained from remote database is different.

I repeatedly get time from database and have a variable which contains the previous time to check if the new time is same as old time. If not I do an operation. I see that the time is exactly same but still the code is executed.

I even check the length of the two strings and they are exactly same. I `Toast` the `string1.equals(string2)` and get false though they are same.

```
    if( (!lastUpdated.equals(prevTime))) {
   swipe(Integer.parseInt(x1.toString()), Integer.parseInt(y1.toString()), Integer.parseInt(x2.toString()), Integer.parseInt(y2.toString()));
    CodeType.setLength(0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), " lastUp " + lastUpdated + ", prevtime " + prevTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), ""+lastUpdated.equals(prevTime), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updatePrevTime(lastUpdated);

   }
```

Comment: reason for downvote please..it's been only a second since i posted the question

Comment: `(!lastUpdated.equals(prevTime))` you're checking for false condition only.

Comment: debug and check actual value in string.

Comment: What are the values of `lastUpdated` and `prevTime` for the case where it is not working as expected?

Comment: well if it's working after you update it that's obviously the issue. We couldn't have helped you though , as you don't include enough code for us to know which type those variables were...

Comment: That's your problem. You're not doing a string comparison at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `StringBuffer`, `equals` will not compare the two `String`s.
Do this:

```
yourStrBuffer.toString().equals(prevTime.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is trailing or leading whitespace in string.
Try this: `lastUpdated.trim().equals(prevTime.trim())`

This should be true if both are equal.

Comment: also i think i should first do `lastUpdated = lastUpdated.trim()` first for both before doing the `.equals` if i used `trim`

Answer (score 0):

Check your lastUpdated and prevTime.

Here is simple example of equals() . Try this should work.

```
  String Str1 = "Hello";
  String Str2 = "Hello";
  boolean retVal;

  retVal = Str1.equals( Str2 );
  System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );
```

> output

```
Returned Value = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextUtils class:

You can try to use TextUtils.equals(CharSeq1, Charseq2) in case you might have missed some cases in your comparison.
The method from TextUtils takes care of the null cases.

If the return method it is still the same then you can try using by char(maybe that fits better than using the standard equals):

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

You can find details about the class here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b2c4f0bf11f38fd31d80f1256c89b9db043a2929/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java

Comment: That is exactly the same as calling `equals` on a String with a String as parameter

Comment: It is not actually the same, look at the method. He can pass the strings or he can try to use Charsequence, as I already stated.

Comment: True, but he is using strings as I understand from the question, in which case your solution is exactly the same as what he already does. See line 480 & 481 of your link

Answer (score 0):

How are times being formatted to string? Do your values contain letters like timezone or period (am/AM)? Can you use the same formatter for both values or use `equalsIgnoreCase()`?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation

In case where strings are not strictly of **String** class, there could be problem in ***.equals()*** method. Recently I have encountered same problem, one was of String class and the other was from ***EditText.getText()***. If you don't pay attention closely, it could be the problem because *getText()* method actually returns ***CharSequence*** which is not same as String, it would have worked elsewhere in the program by auto conversion but not in ***.equal()*** . But using ***getText().toString()*** gave correct result because now I'm comparing two objects of strictly String class.

(Hoping it would be helpful for someone.)

Same problem happens when it comes from Stream classes as internally it deals with characters and also could be due to encoding. So check them out.